# How to pass the non dataframe argument to udf in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Can any please help to know how to pass the non dataframe value as an argument to udf.

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("newcol", udffunc(df1("col1"), x)).
```

The udf function i defined as below.

```
udffunc = udf(method _)
```

Method i defined as below.

```
def method(inputvar1: String, inputvar2: String): Option[Long] = {
  ...
  ...
  return Longvariable
}
```

Comment: Compile error. Its not allowing to pass the argument x as a argument. Can any one please help.

Comment: In the sbt console, could you run `:type udffunc`?

Comment: @Reactormonk: I did not get your question

Comment: I am working on IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: As per online looks like using withColumn there is no direct way to pass the external argument like hardcoding some string like I said.

Comment: But i think we can pass that argument string "x" through udf. So code will be like,                                                                                                                 val df2 = df1.withColumn("newcol", udffunc(df1("col1")))                                    udffunc = udf(method _)  Here while creating a udf i need modify the code such that it will pass 2 arguments to the method                                         def method(inputvar1: String, inputvar2: String): Option[Long] = {
  ...
  ...
  return Longvariable
}

Comment: Can any one please help in knowing how to write udf to pass two arguments even though it receives one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue by just writing the below code for UDF.

```
def udffunc = udf((y:String) => {
    val format:String = "x"
    method(y, "x")
  })
```

So with this, I am able to pass one argument(dataframe column) from .withColumn to the UDF function `udffunc` and then am able to pass external argument which is "x" in the above example to the function named as "method".

Comment: I'd recommend to always use `val` instead of `var` whenever possible. Immutable code is robust code.

Comment: Hi, using lit function i can pass the non dataframe argument from withColumn. Here is the code.                                                                      val df2 = df1.withColumn(df1("col1"), lit(x))